# Get Storage Account Key of newly create storage account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, arm

I am trying to get a newly storage account Key with C# but it gives me exception that

> Exception Message - The storage account provisioning state must be 'Succeeded' before executing the operation.
>   Stack Trace -    at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageAccountsOperations.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageAccountsOperationsExtensions.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at PPS.Controllers.ManageResourcesController.d__33.MoveNext()

In my requirement which is that I need to create a new storage account with a specified location and upload files in it. I am able to create a new storage account through Azure REST API but when I try to get the newly storage account key it gives me exception as I explained above. Below is the code which I am using for creation and get the storage account key

```
string token = GetAccessToken();
var Credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);



            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(Credentials);
            resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = SubscriptionID;

            var storageProvider = resourceManagementClient.Providers.Register("Microsoft.Storage");

            var storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClient(Credentials);
            storageManagementClient.SubscriptionId = SubscriptionID;

            string rgName = "Test" + location.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            var resourceGroup = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources.Models.ResourceGroup
            {
                Location = location
            };
            var rgResult = resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdate(rgName, resourceGroup);

            string stAccName = "TCStAccount"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
            stAccName = stAccName.ToLower();

            sku sk = new sku();
            sk.name = "Standard_LRS";

            storagesettings st = new storagesettings();
            st.kind = "Storage";
            st.location = location;
            st.sku = sk;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    var payloadText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(st);

                    writer.Write(payloadText);
                    writer.Flush();
                    stream.Flush();
                    stream.Position = 0;

                    using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
                    {
                        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2016-12-01");
                        Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{2}?api-version=2016-12-01", SubscriptionID, rgName, stAccName));

                        var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
                        string detailError = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var storageAccountKey = await storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.ListKeysAsync(rgName, stAccName);
            string storage_Account_Key = storageAccountKey.Keys[0].Value;
```

Let me know If I miss anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you could find:

> The storage account provisioning state must be 'Succeeded' before executing the operation.

After you have created the storage account, azure will **begin** creating the storage account.

It will take some time, almost 10 seconds.

Before the storage account created successfully, you couldn't get the storage access key.

You could use thread.sleep() method to wait the storage account created successfully, then send the request again to ask the storage account key.

It will work well.

Comment: `You could use thread.sleep() method to wait the storage account created successfully, then send the request again to ask the storage account key.` - IMHO, a better option would be to fetch storage account properties and check for provisioning status periodically (using thread.sleep()) and only get storage account keys when the provisioning status is successful.